# MediaCodec.release() causes crashes: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) in _ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv

Tags: android-mediacodec

An app is quite stable.  The vast majority of its occasional crashes are caused by MediaCodec.release() in the following code:

```
mediaCodec.stop()
mediaCodec.release();
```

or

```
mediaCodec.reset()
mediaCodec.release();
```

The exception cannot be caught.  Could anyone offer some tips on how to find a remedy for this?
Here are a few examples of the crashes reported by Google Play:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv

Motorola Moto G(4) Plus (athene_f), Android 7.0
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000bd98  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+11)
  #01  pc 00000000000c0acf  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodecD1Ev+250)
  #02  pc 00000000000c0cc7  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodecD0Ev+2)
  #03  pc 000000000000bdc7  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+58)
  #04  pc 000000000001fec7  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (_ZN7android11JMediaCodec7releaseEv+22)
  #05  pc 00000000000233eb  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
  #06  pc 0000000000021273  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
  #07  pc 0000000001a5532f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.native_release+74)
  #08  pc 0000000001a56d6b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.release+54)
  #09  pc 00000000000a91c1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #10  pc 00000000004031e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+232)
  #11  pc 00000000000b0455  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+136)
  #12  pc 00000000001ec389  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+200)
  #13  pc 00000000001e6939  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+492)
  #14  pc 00000000003fd663  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+322)
  #15  pc 000000000009fd94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #16  pc 00000000001ca783  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #17  pc 00000000001cf2eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
  #18  pc 00000000001e691f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
  #19  pc 00000000003fbe09  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+236)
  #20  pc 000000000009c194  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #21  pc 00000000001ca783  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #22  pc 00000000001cf2eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
  #23  pc 00000000001e691f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
  #24  pc 00000000003fbb2d  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+268)
  #25  pc 000000000009c114  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
  #26  pc 00000000001ca783  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #27  pc 00000000001cf2eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
  #28  pc 00000000001e691f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
  #29  pc 00000000003fd663  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+322)
  #30  pc 000000000009fd94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #31  pc 00000000001ca783  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #32  pc 00000000001cf255  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
  #33  pc 00000000003f269f  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+706)
  #34  pc 00000000000adc13  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
  #35  pc 00000000005f749d  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+48)
  #36  pc 00000000000a91c1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #37  pc 00000000004031e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+232)
  #38  pc 00000000000b0455  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+136)
  #39  pc 0000000000314031  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+56)
  #40  pc 0000000000314dfd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+256)
  #41  pc 000000000032be19  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+848)
  #42  pc 0000000000046eb3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
  #43  pc 0000000000019acd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)




Sony Xperia XZ2 Compact (H8314), Android 8.0
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000d704  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+28)
  #01  pc 000000000003051c  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (_ZL32android_media_MediaCodec_releaseP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+52)



Huawei P10 Plus (HWVKY), Android 8.0
Report 1 of 1
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.biyee.onvifer <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000d774  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+28)
  #01  pc 000000000003081c  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (_ZL32android_media_MediaCodec_releaseP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+52)
  #02  pc 00000000006249ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.destroy [DEDUPED]+124)
  #03  pc 0000000000d9e68c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.release+284)
  #04  pc 0000000000509384  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #05  pc 00000000000d8078  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #06  pc 00000000002821dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #07  pc 000000000027c8a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
  #08  pc 00000000004f3d30  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #09  pc 00000000004fea94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #10  pc 000000000025d620  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #11  pc 0000000000263d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #12  pc 000000000027c884  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #13  pc 00000000004f2130  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+468)
  #14  pc 00000000004fae94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #15  pc 000000000025d620  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #16  pc 0000000000263d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #17  pc 000000000027c884  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #18  pc 00000000004f1e78  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+504)
  #19  pc 00000000004fae14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
  #20  pc 000000000025d620  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #21  pc 0000000000263d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #22  pc 000000000027c884  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #23  pc 00000000004f3d30  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #24  pc 00000000004fea94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #25  pc 000000000025d620  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #26  pc 00000000004e4a88  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #27  pc 000000000051281c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #28  pc 00000000001fd13c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+76)
  #29  pc 0000000000509384  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #30  pc 00000000000d8078  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #31  pc 000000000043111c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
  #32  pc 00000000004322a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+432)
  #33  pc 0000000000458e88  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1140)
  #34  pc 0000000000066a20  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
  #35  pc 000000000001ee64  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)




Google Chromebook (edgar_cheets), Android 7.1
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000d6ec  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9incStrongEPKv+28)
  #01  pc 00000000001081f9  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodec27ResourceManagerServiceProxyD2Ev+89)
  #02  pc 0000000000108414  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZTv0_n12_N7android10MediaCodec27ResourceManagerServiceProxyD0Ev+52)
  #03  pc 000000000000d797  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+87)
  #04  pc 0000000000109f52  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodecD1Ev+882)
  #05  pc 000000000010a221  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaCodecD0Ev+33)
  #06  pc 000000000000d797  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+87)
  #07  pc 000000000002715e  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (_ZN7android11JMediaCodec7releaseEv+62)
  #08  pc 000000000002c90f  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
  #09  pc 00000000000296d6  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
  #10  pc 00000000023d5eac  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (void android.media.MediaCodec.native_release()+104)
  #11  pc 00000000023d828f  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (void android.media.MediaCodec.release()+59)
  #12  pc 000000000010c562  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
  #13  pc 00000000001160dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+237)
  #14  pc 0000000000327326  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+294)
  #15  pc 000000000031ee98  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+728)
  #16  pc 00000000006955e7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+535)
  #17  pc 00000000001025a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+29857)
  #18  pc 00000000002ef888  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
  #19  pc 00000000002f70d0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
  #20  pc 000000000031ee7b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+699)
  #21  pc 0000000000692e0e  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+414)
  #22  pc 00000000000fe9a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
  #23  pc 00000000002ef888  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
  #24  pc 00000000002f70d0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
  #25  pc 000000000031ee7b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+699)
  #26  pc 0000000000692910  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+464)
  #27  pc 00000000000fe921  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14369)
  #28  pc 00000000002ef888  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
  #29  pc 00000000002f70d0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+192)
  #30  pc 000000000031ee7b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+699)
  #31  pc 00000000006955e7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+535)
  #32  pc 00000000001025a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+29857)
  #33  pc 00000000002ef888  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+488)
  #34  pc 00000000002f6fe0  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+176)
  #35  pc 00000000006838b6  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+998)
  #36  pc 000000000011269d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
  #37  pc 00000000007a5c0c  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (void java.lang.Thread.run()+72)
  #38  pc 000000000010c562  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
  #39  pc 00000000001160dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+237)
  #40  pc 0000000000525145  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+101)
  #41  pc 00000000005266c2  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+370)
  #42  pc 000000000054edc9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1657)
  #43  pc 0000000000085a72  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
  #44  pc 000000000002f73e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
  #45  pc 000000000002d3f6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)



Motorola Moto Z (2) Play (albus), Android 8.0
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000adac  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+11)
  #01  pc 0000000000020b09  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so (_ZL32android_media_MediaCodec_releaseP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+36)
  #02  pc 00000000005d26d3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.destroy [DEDUPED]+74)
  #03  pc 0000000000c033f9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.release+56)
  #04  pc 00000000003dd461  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #05  pc 00000000003e19d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
  #06  pc 00000000000ac4ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
  #07  pc 00000000001f28af  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+238)
  #08  pc 00000000001ede5f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+574)
  #09  pc 00000000003c9979  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+504)
  #10  pc 00000000003d3494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #11  pc 00000000001d53e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #12  pc 00000000001da763  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #13  pc 00000000001ede49  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+552)
  #14  pc 00000000003c8455  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+324)
  #15  pc 00000000003cf894  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #16  pc 00000000001d53e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #17  pc 00000000001da763  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #18  pc 00000000001eea2d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+420)
  #19  pc 00000000003c9c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuickRange+378)
  #20  pc 00000000003d3514  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+30100)
  #21  pc 00000000001d53e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #22  pc 00000000001da763  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #23  pc 00000000001ede49  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+552)
  #24  pc 00000000003c9979  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+504)
  #25  pc 00000000003d3494  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #26  pc 00000000001d53e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #27  pc 00000000001da6b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
  #28  pc 00000000003bdadd  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+960)
  #29  pc 00000000003e1221  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #30  pc 00000000001ee141  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64)
  #31  pc 00000000003dd461  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #32  pc 00000000003e19d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
  #33  pc 00000000000ac4ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
  #34  pc 0000000000332b7d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
  #35  pc 00000000003339f1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
  #36  pc 0000000000351261  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
  #37  pc 0000000000047dc7  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
  #38  pc 000000000001b0b5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)



Samsung Galaxy S9 (starlte), Android 8.0
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000d8c0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+32)
  #01  pc 00000000000330c4  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (_ZL32android_media_MediaCodec_releaseP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+52)
  #02  pc 000000000069290c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.destroy [DEDUPED]+124)
  #03  pc 0000000000e07ebc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.release+60)
  #04  pc 000000000052db84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #05  pc 00000000000d8688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #06  pc 0000000000291800  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #07  pc 000000000028be38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+680)
  #08  pc 0000000000518388  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #09  pc 0000000000523214  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #10  pc 000000000026c000  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+448)
  #11  pc 00000000002728e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #12  pc 000000000028be18  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+648)
  #13  pc 0000000000516754  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+468)
  #14  pc 000000000051f614  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #15  pc 000000000026c000  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+448)
  #16  pc 0000000000508dc0  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1472)
  #17  pc 000000000053701c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #18  pc 0000000000068ad8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_18573_18573 (deleted)



OnePlus OnePlus3T (OnePlus3T), Android 8.0
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> net.mydomain.foo <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000000d704  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZNK7android7RefBase9decStrongEPKv+28)
  #01  pc 000000000002fdd4  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (_ZL32android_media_MediaCodec_releaseP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+52)
  #02  pc 000000000060e90c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.destroy [DEDUPED]+124)
  #03  pc 0000000000d69fbc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.release+60)
  #04  pc 0000000000506b84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #05  pc 00000000000d80bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #06  pc 0000000000281714  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #07  pc 000000000027bddc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
  #08  pc 00000000004f15f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #09  pc 00000000004fc394  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #10  pc 000000000025cb58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #11  pc 0000000000263258  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #12  pc 000000000027bdbc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #13  pc 00000000004ef9f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+468)
  #14  pc 00000000004f8794  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #15  pc 000000000025cb58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #16  pc 0000000000263258  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #17  pc 000000000027cc2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+584)
  #18  pc 00000000004f19f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuickRange+516)
  #19  pc 00000000004fc414  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+30100)
  #20  pc 000000000025cb58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #21  pc 0000000000263258  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #22  pc 000000000027bdbc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #23  pc 00000000004f15f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #24  pc 00000000004fc394  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #25  pc 000000000025cb58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #26  pc 00000000004e2350  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #27  pc 000000000051001c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #28  pc 00000000001febfc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-oj.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+76)
  #29  pc 0000000000506b84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #30  pc 00000000000d80bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #31  pc 000000000042f860  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+104)
  #32  pc 00000000004309ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+432)
  #33  pc 0000000000456df4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1140)
  #34  pc 000000000006679c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
  #35  pc 000000000001f2b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error on SM-G965F running Android 8.0.0.

Comment: Android 8.0 seems to be particularly prone to this.